# Blender Asset Library - drag and drop alignment problem: how do I make library objects snap/align on their top instead of bottom face?

Tags: asset-browser, asset

I have a library of objects (windows, doors etc.) in my Asset Library.

When I drag and drop them on existing cube (building) they snap on the surface, using the closest surface of the dropped object. I'd like to make my objects in a way that they snap by some point in the middle of the objects, i.e. window would drop and snap below the surface of the building.

I then use boolean modifier on the whole collection of windows and doors so they go inside the building and look like cavities. I tried moving the library object's origin - but it's not what Blender is using for alignment.

Is there a way to change the alignment options, or exclude some surfaces from alignment? I need my windows snapped on their top surface (frame), not the bottom surface (glass).